# What will happen to these colliding strings?

Tags: string-theory, vibrations

What happens when these two strings collide? Do they cancel each other out, pass through each other or interact in some way?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: They are attached at the ends?

Comment: Yes they are attached at the ends

Comment: The only way I can see to realize this scenario in string theory, is to have two D0-branes (0-dimensional branes, point-branes), and then have two strings stretching between them. So the strings aren't directly attached to each other, but rather they are both anchored to the same pointlike D-branes... Is this definitely the scenario you want analyzed?

Comment: Yeah this is the scenario I want analyzed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two strings touch at a point, they can interact by recombining:

[image]

That is, if the midpoints of your two strings come into contact, the four "half-strings" can pair up differently, and then go their separate ways as two new strings.

(In the upper right picture, the green string is not broken, it's just "behind" the blue string.)